# How to create page visit counting like PHP session on JavaScript (client) side

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a session number of page view/visit like PHP, but in JavaScript?

```
$_SESSION['views'] = 0;
```

Is it possible to keep track of the number even when user quite the page and get back again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Cookies. On visit get the cookie and increment it by 1. Or set it to 1 if it doesn't exist

Example:

```
<p id="yolo"> </p>

<script>
    var numberOfVisits = function getCookie('numberOfVisits');

    if (numberOfVisits == "")
    {
        setcookie('numberOfVisits', 1, 100);
    }
    else
    {
        numberOfVisits++;
        setcookie('numberOfVisits', numberOfVisits, 100);
    }

    document.getElementById('yolo').innerHTML = getCookie('numberOfVisits');

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    function setcookie(name, value, days)
    {
        if (days)
        {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+days*24*60*60*1000);
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else
        {
            var expires = "";
        }
        document.cookie = name+"=" + value+expires + ";path=/";added
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lots @dustytrash, but can u also please let me know how can I display the result

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the data on the client side then use 
`window.localStorage`, it stores data with no expiration date on the client side and it does not send it to the server on every request like cookies, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies).

```js
<script>

var varname = "VISIT_COUNTER";
 if (localStorage.getItem(varname) === null) {
        localStorage.setItem(varname, 1);
 } else { 
        var visits_count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(varname)) + 1;
        localStorage.setItem(varname, visits_count);
        console.log("Total visits: " + visits_count);
 }

</script>
```